# Computed data in table not updating after changing radio value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following problem with the data table I'm trying to implement in my VueJS frontend. When I try to change the supplier, the price needs to be updated in the cost column on the far right column of the table, and same for the total cost given by a computed property. I don't understand why the data is not being updated, I've tried this.$forceUpdate() and nothing works..

Thanks for your help.

[image]

```
    <template>
   <div>
      <v-row>
         <v-col
             cols="2">
            <v-date-picker
                v-model="dateRange"
                range show-adjacent-months
                @input="fetchWeeklyIngredients"/>

            <h1>Total cost: ${{Math.round(totalCost)}}</h1>
         </v-col>
         <v-col>
            <v-simple-table>
               <template v-slot:default>
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th class="text-left">
                        Ingredient
                     </th>
                     <th class="text-left">
                        Weight
                     </th>
                     <th class="text-left">
                        Status
                     </th>
                     <th class="text-left">
                        Suppliers
                     </th>
                     <th class="text-left">
                        Cost
                     </th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr
                      v-for="ingredient in ingredients"
                      :key="ingredient.id">
                     <td>{{ ingredient.name }}</td>
                     <td>{{ Math.round(ingredient.weight*100)/100 }}</td>
                     <td>{{ ingredient.status }}</td>
                     <td>
                        <v-radio-group
                            v-if="ingredient.suppliers.length"
                            v-model="ingredient.selectedSupplier">
                           <v-radio
                               v-for="supplier in ingredient.suppliers"
                               :key="supplier.id"
                               :value="supplier"
                               :label="supplier.name+' | Priority: '+supplier.priority+' | Price: '+supplier.cost"/>
                        </v-radio-group>
                     </td>

                     <td v-if="ingredient.selectedSupplier">
                        {{Math.round(ingredient.weight*ingredient.selectedSupplier.cost)}}
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </template>
            </v-simple-table>
         </v-col>
      </v-row>
   </div>
</template>



<script>

import axios from 'axios'
export default {
   name: "WeeklyIngredients",
   data(){
      return{
         dateRange:[],
         ingredients: [],
         headers:[
            {
               text: 'Ingredient',
               align: 'start',
               sortable: true,
               value: 'name',
            },
            {
               text: 'Weight',
               value: 'weight',
               sortable: true
            },
            {
               text: 'Status',
               value: 'status',
               sortable: true
            },
            {
               text: 'Suppliers',
               value: 'suppliers',
               sortable: false
            },
            {
               text: 'Cost',
               value: 'cost',
               sortable: true
            }
         ],
         loading: false,
         itemsPerPage: 10
      }
   },
   computed:{
      sortedDateRange(){
         return this.dateRange.sort()
      },
      totalCost(){
        return this.ingredients
             .filter(ingredient => ingredient.selectedSupplier)
             .reduce((totalCost, ingredient) =>
                 totalCost + ingredient.weight*ingredient.selectedSupplier.cost,
                 0)
      }
   },
   methods:{
      fetchWeeklyIngredients(){
         if(this.sortedDateRange.length<2){return;}

         this.loading = true;

         axios.get("/kitchenReport/ingredients/"+this.sortedDateRange[0]+"/"+this.sortedDateRange[1])
             .then(({data}) => {
                this.ingredients = data.ingredients;
                this.ingredients.map((ingredient,index) => {
                   if(ingredient.suppliers.length>0){
                      this.ingredients[index].selectedSupplier = this.ingredients[index].suppliers[0];
                   }
                })
                this.loading=false;
             })
      },
      selectedSupplierCost(suppliers){
         if(!suppliers.length>0){return 0;}

         const selectedSupplier = suppliers.find(supplier => supplier.selected)
         return (selectedSupplier ? selectedSupplier.cost : 0)
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

EDIT: This is the structure of the ingredients array of objects:

[image]

Comment: Can you share an example of ingredient object. With this code, there is no idea about the structure of the ingredient object inside the

Comment: @VikumDheemantha you're right, I've just edited the post, thanks

Comment: did you try to check the `selectedSupplier` is updating properly by vue developer tool extensions? I could not found any issues yet.